# Layout of text/spacing changes in TextArea when clicking on it

Tags: layout, textarea, codenameone, spacing

I have a CodenameOne application which has a TextArea that should display a multi-line text.

When I run the app in the simulator and click on the text-area, the spacing between the lines and possibly also between the characters change so that the area that the text occupies shrinks a bit.

Why is this?
What should I do to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

That is due to the switch from our drawing to the native editing which will always render things slightly differently. E.g. things like line spacing are really hard to get accurately for every native device.

`TextArea` has a `setRowsGap` method that allows you to specify the spacing between rows in pixels but since this differs between OS's its probably not ideal.

Comment: OK, so is there a better way to display a multi-line text which doesn't have this problem?  I tried the SpanLabel but couldn't get that scrollable if the text was too large.

Comment: I assumed you wanted to edit the text, if you don't want to edit it just set editable to false (`setEditable(false)`) and it won't do that anymore...